# OutOfMemory error when using Apache Commons lineIterator

Tags: java, scala, out-of-memory, apache-commons, fileutils

I'm trying to iterate line-by-line a 1.2GB file using Apache Commons `FileUtils.lineIterator`. However, as soon as a `LineIterator` calls `hasNext()` I get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. I've already allocated `1G` to the java heap.

What am I doing wrong in here? After reading some docs, isn't LineIterator supposed to be reading the file from the file system and not loading it into memory?

Note the code is in Scala:

```
  val file = new java.io.File("data_export.dat")
  val it = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.lineIterator(file, "UTF-8")
  var successCount = 0L
  var totalCount = 0L
  try {
    while ( {
      it.hasNext()
    }) {
      try {
        val legacy = parse[LegacyEvent](it.nextLine())
        BehaviorEvent(legacy)
        successCount += 1L
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => println("Parse error")
      }
      totalCount += 1
    }
  } finally {
    it.close()
  }
```

Thanks for your help here!

Comment: wow at this moment we have exact same number of points :) - 3642

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov haha i wonder what the statistical coincide of that is? let me load the StackOverflow dataset line-by-line and back to you :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code looks good. Probably it does not find an end of a line in the file and reads a very long line which is larger than 1Gb into memory.

Try `wc -l` in Unix and see how many lines you get.

Comment: Oh crap, you're right! I didn't realize that it was a single, massive line. Here's the result from `wc -l`: `0 data_export.dat`. I'll have to reformat the data. I'll accept this ASAP. Thanks!